# How do I pipe commands together in a debian preseed file?

Tags: linux, debian

I would like to know if it is possible to pipe commands together in a preseed file.

Something Like:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string yes N | apt-get install package -y
```

(I realize this is a somewhat bad example. I just wanted to know if/how it would work.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do that at the last stage, these are some examples to give you an idea:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
cd /target/etc/apt/; \
wget http://repo.example.com/sources_new.list; \
mv sources_new.list sources.list; \
echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy.example.org";' >> apt.conf; \
ls . > temp; \
cat temp | grep -cq string; \
cd /; \
in-target apt-get update; \
in-target apt-get -y upgrade; \
in-target apt-get -y dist-upgrade; \
in-target tasksel install desktop; \
in-target apt-get -y install sudo \
less \
ssh \
icedove \
lynx \
xscreensaver;
```

So the target filesystem by default is located at /target and you can move around and copy and delete files, edit files and if you want to run a command in the target filesystem you use "in-target" before the command.

For more documentation see: http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/manual/en.amd64/apbs05.html#preseed-hooks

Comment: Sure, but there are no piped commands in your example. "cat file | grep "thing" > newFile"

Comment: See my answer for an updated example, albeit useless in this case. :-)

Comment: Just for being sure, would this also work dropping multile `d-i preseed/late_command` or is there a specific reason you put everything in one?

Comment: I think you can not, however since you can string commands together as I showed in my answer this shouldn't be a problem. See also http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/possible-create-more-than-one-preseed-late-command-help-206863512.html

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the commands via `/bin/sh`. This allows you to use pipes. Example:

```
in-target /bin/sh -c -- 'blkid /dev/sda1 | xargs -n1 | grep "^UUID=" >/tmp/uuid-sda1.txt'
```