# Passing variables to use in the preseed file for a Debian Jessie installation

Tags: debian, environment-variables, preseed, packer

Is it possible to add a variable via the boot prompt to the Debian installer, so that variable can be used in a preseed file?

In particular, I'm trying to solve the following problem:

We have a pretty extensive post-install script that is generally downloaded from a server. But now I want to create Packer images and keep the post-install script in version control together with the other Packer files. For accessing the preseed, I can do "preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg" in the boot command. But now I want the installer to download the post-install script from that same location.

Currently, the post-install hook looks like this:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string wget -q -O /tmp/postinstall.sh http://our.public.server/postinstall.jessie.sh ; sh /tmp/postinstall.sh
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string wget -q -O /tmp/postinstall.sh http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/postinstall.jessie.sh ; sh /tmp/postinstall.sh
```

But of course the Debian installer will not replace those with the required values. So I was thinking that it might be possible to pass environment variable-like variables to the installer that we can use in the preseed file.

Any hints or tips are appreciated!

EDIT: Tried adding the late_command to the boot command, but that didn't get picked up.

EDIT: Tried preseed/run, but it runs in a different environment which does not allow the in-target command.

EDIT: This can be a workaround: [How do I pipe commands together in a debian preseed file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/390122/how-do-i-pipe-commands-together-in-a-debian-preseed-file) But I'd prefer to have the script in a separate file. If it's not possible, it's not possible, though.

Comment: How did you add this postinstall.sh to temp folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself (with some help from @lieter_). Not too proud of it, but it works:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string wget -q -O /tmp/postinstall.sh http://`cat /proc/cmdline | sed 's/.*url=\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/'`/d-i/jessie/postinstall.sh ; sh /tmp/postinstall.sh
```

This does what I need, since we always add a url= to our command line when installing.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what OS you are using, but the Linux kernel will let you specify environment variables as kernel parameters. The Linux kernel [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html) has some good information around it (important paragraph bolded):

> #### The argument list
>
> The kernel command line is parsed into a list of
>   strings (boot  arguments) separated by spaces.  Most of the boot
>   arguments have the  form:
>
> ```
>  name[=value_1][,value_2]...[,value_10]
> ```
>
> where 'name' is a unique keyword that is used to identify what part 
>   of the kernel the associated values (if any) are to be given to.  Note
>   the limit of 10 is real, as the present code handles only 10  comma
>   separated parameters per keyword.  (However, you can reuse the  same
>   keyword with up to an additional 10 parameters in unusually complicated situations, > assuming the setup function supports it.)
>
> Most of the sorting is coded in the kernel source file init/main.c. 
>   First, the kernel checks to see if the argument is any of the special 
>   arguments 'root=', 'nfsroot=', 'nfsaddrs=', 'ro', 'rw', 'debug' or 
>   'init'.  The meaning of these special arguments is described below.
>
> Then it walks a list of setup functions to see if the specified argument string 
>   (such as 'foo') has been associated with a setup function 
>   ('foo_setup()') for a particular device or part of the kernel.  If 
>   you passed the kernel the line foo=3,4,5,6 then the kernel would 
>   search the bootsetups array to see if 'foo' was registered.  If it 
>   was, then it would call the setup function associated with 'foo' 
>   (foo_setup()) and hand it the arguments 3, 4, 5, and 6 as given on 
>   the kernel command line.
>
> **Anything of the form 'foo=bar' that is not accepted as a setup function as 
>   described above is then interpreted as an environment variable to be set.
>
>   A (useless?) example would be to use 'TERM=vt100' as 
>   a boot argument.**
>
> Any remaining arguments that were not picked up by the kernel and 
>   were not interpreted as environment variables are then passed onto 
>   PID 1, which is usually the init(1) program.  The most common argument 
>   that is passed to the init process is the word 'single' which 
>   instructs it to boot the computer in single user mode, and not launch 
>   all the usual daemons.  Check the manual page for the version of 
>   init(1) installed on your system to see what arguments it accepts.

Here is my `boot_command` section in my `virtualbox-iso` builder (for Ubuntu 18.04):

```
boot_command:
  - '<esc><esc><enter><wait>'
  - '/install/vmlinuz noapic fb=false '
  - 'auto=true '
  - 'hostname={{.Name}} '
  - 'url=http://{{.HTTPIP}}:{{.HTTPPort}}/ubuntu.seed '
  - 'initrd=/install/initrd.gz '
  - 'http_proxy={{user `http_proxy`}} '
  - 'packer_host={{.HTTPIP}} '
  - 'packer_port={{.HTTPPort}} '
  - 'hello=world '
  - 'quiet --- <enter>'
```

The `http_proxy`, `packer_host`, `packer_port`, and `hello` parameters are completely optional, and will be converted into environment variables by the kernel.

In my `ubuntu.seed` file, I have the following line to print out the `hello` environment variable into a file:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string echo $hello > /target/home/packer/hello
```

When I import and start up the OVA, that file will be in my home directory with `world` as its contents.

Answer (score 2):

While looking to solve much the same issue I learned about some magic that is baked into the `debian-installer`. You can use `preseed_fetch` to pull from the URL if you add a `/./` at the point in the URL that you want to set as the `rootpath` for other commands to perform their relative fetches against.

Given a server with a preseed folder and a scripts folder with other files you want to use, if you pass `url=http://{{.HTTPIP}}:{{.HTTPPort}}/http/./preseed/ubuntu.seed` you can then reference other files relative to the root path like `preseed_fetch /scripts/somescript.sh /tmp/somescript.sh`.

```
d-i preseed/late_command    string preseed_fetch /scripts/late_script /tmp/late_script; \
 log-output -t late_script sh /tmp/late_script
```

More information can be found at https://hands.com/d-i/lenny/start.cfg and https://hands.com/d-i/ under the heading "url=magic".

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why you were downvoted. This appears to be the official documented way. It worked perfectly, although I had to add `d-i preseed/early_command string echo "$(debconf-get preseed/url)" >/var/run/preseed.last_location` to my preseed file due to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=678694